# Convert Base64 String to Image file in Groovy

Tags: image, groovy, base64

i checked with old threads but didn't find anything helpful.
i am a JD Edwards developer and we have a requirement in jde Orchestrator to process base64 string.

Can anyone help me and share full code for this?

i am new in groovy script.

Comment: `new File('filename').bytes = "base64string".decodeBase64()`

Comment: do we need to add more something  and also filenames means full path for file including name i.e. C:\Users\arunkmishra\Desktop\image.png and decodeBase64(inputstring).
Can you please share some example code?
it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def base64str = 'R0lGODlhAwADAHAAACwAAAAAAwADAIHsHCT97KYAAAAAAAACBIQRBwUAOw==' // < base64 string with 3x3 gif inside
def filename = System.properties['user.home']+'/documents/my.gif'              // < filename with path

// save decoded base64 bytes into file
new File(filename).bytes = base64str.decodeBase64()
```

as a result you there should be a new file `my.gif` in `current user/ documents` folder
with 3x3 pixels image (43 bytes file)